# CSS небольщая анимация

Tags: html, css

есть такой файл и есть задача сделать, что-бы эти элементы просто крутились.[image: она должна крутитсься] как в этом видео: https://youtu.be/bHehkFPLvc0?t=136 только без остановки)

Comment: в этом видео про бутылок говоритсья

Comment: Зачем мне бутылки?

Comment: автор жжет!!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  perspective: 600px;
}

.items {
  width: 40vw;
  height: 40vw;
  margin: 2vw auto;
  transform: rotateX(30deg);
  perspective: 600px;
  outline:3px solid red;
}

section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: -30px -40px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.items span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 90%;
  margin: 10px;
  background: green;
  animation: move 4s linear infinite;
  transform: translate(-0, 0)rotateX(-30deg)
}

@keyframes move {
  0% {
    transform: translate(300px, 0)rotateX(-30deg)
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(-300px, 0)rotateX(-30deg)
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <section>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Макс, зеленые полосы, надо было реализовать с виде бутылок)))))

Comment: @Air  ак он же вроде бы .. даже картинку показал ..  просто вниз ни делал треугольник ..

Comment: Макс, это была шутка)))) Тебе надо бы повысить уровень чувства юмора))))

Comment: @Air  да ..у меня напряжёнка с юмором ...видел мой пример с паралаксом ?

Comment: Нет, Макс, скинь ссылку

Comment: @Air  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/834320/33274