# Блюр картинки при скроллинге вниз

Tags: html, css

не могу понять, как реализовать такое, как на картинке в header.
уже перерыл множество инфы, подтолкните плз
[пример](https://www.residentadvisor.net/features/3191)

Comment: А какую именно картинку на этой страницы вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: @IliaBrykin residentadvisor.net/images/features/2018/march-best-music.jpg вот картинка, при скроллинге вниз, появляется блюр, я хотел бы сделать на своём сайте аналогично)

Comment: эффект происходит на событие браузера - скролл, отловить его можно при помощи javascript, [тут](https://learn.javascript.ru/metrics-window) подробнее

Answer (score 1):

На том сайте применён не один эффект а несколько

1) blur...

2) parallax...

3) sticky для среднего элемента (в моём случае main)

*Этот пример в песочнице на весь экран* [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/topicstarter/full/gKYYaR/) *здесь как всегда не так отображается*

я попытался реализовать все эффекты которые там увидел `смотри на полный экран`

```js
var elem = $(".blur");
var elem1 = $("header").height();
var elem3 = $(".noblur");
var elem4 = $("main");
var elem5 = $(".container");
var elem6 = $("main").height();

$(document).ready(function($) {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scroll >= elem1) {
      $(elem4).css({
        "position": "fixed",
        "top": "0",
        "left": "0",
        "width": "100vw",
        "z-index": 50
      });
      $(elem5).css({
        "position": "relative",
        "margin-top": elem1 + '10vh',
        "z-index": 100,
        "width": "100vw",
        "transition": "0.5s"
      })
      $(elem).css({
        "filter": "blur(20px)"
      });
      $(elem3).css({
        "opacity": "1",
        "transform": "translate(0,-200px)",
        "transition": "1s"
      });
    } else {
      $("html,body").css({
        "padding-top": 0
      });
      $(elem4).css({
        "position": "relative"
      })
      $(elem).css({
        "filter": "blur(0)"
      });
      $(elem3).css({
        "opacity": "0",
        "transform": "translate(0,0)"
      })
    }
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  max-width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20vh;
  background: lightgreen;
}

main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80vh;
  position: relative;
}

.blur {
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  transition: .5s;
}

.noblur {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  width: inherit;
  height: auto;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .5s;
}

.noblur ul {
  padding: 20px 40px;
}

.noblur a {
  font-size: 2em;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

.color:first-child {
  width: 10vw;
  height: 10vw;
  background: violet;
}

.color:nth-child(2) {
  width: 30vw;
  height: 30vw;
  background: lightblue;
}

.color:nth-child(3) {
  width: 20vw;
  height: 20vw;
  background: yellow;
}

.container {
  width: 100vw;
  background: #fff;
  min-height: 50vh;
  padding: 20px;
}

.container p {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 30px auto;
  font-size: 1.4em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header></header>
<main>
  <section class="blur">
    <div class="color"></div>
    <div class="color"></div>
    <div class="color"></div>
    <div class="color"></div>
  </section>
  <section class="noblur">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">blog</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">contacts</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">portfolio</a></li>
    </ul>
  </section>
</main>
<div class="container">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid, ipsum. Tempore recusandae tempora laboriosam soluta maiores dolores tenetur iusto quas culpa. Recusandae reprehenderit animi veniam voluptates tempora unde. Qui assumenda reprehenderit
    provident delectus natus illum eos accusamus perspiciatis. Reiciendis culpa debitis consequatur dignissimos aliquid laborum! Eaque cupiditate soluta voluptate eius!</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid, ipsum. Tempore recusandae tempora laboriosam soluta maiores dolores tenetur iusto quas culpa. Recusandae reprehenderit animi veniam voluptates tempora unde. Qui assumenda reprehenderit
    provident delectus natus illum eos accusamus perspiciatis. Reiciendis culpa debitis consequatur dignissimos aliquid laborum! Eaque cupiditate soluta voluptate eius!</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid, ipsum. Tempore recusandae tempora laboriosam soluta maiores dolores tenetur iusto quas culpa. Recusandae reprehenderit animi veniam voluptates tempora unde. Qui assumenda reprehenderit
    provident delectus natus illum eos accusamus perspiciatis. Reiciendis culpa debitis consequatur dignissimos aliquid laborum! Eaque cupiditate soluta voluptate eius!</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid, ipsum. Tempore recusandae tempora laboriosam soluta maiores dolores tenetur iusto quas culpa. Recusandae reprehenderit animi veniam voluptates tempora unde. Qui assumenda reprehenderit
    provident delectus natus illum eos accusamus perspiciatis. Reiciendis culpa debitis consequatur dignissimos aliquid laborum! Eaque cupiditate soluta voluptate eius!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Хорошая реализация...

Comment: @Air  я не могу только высчитать translate(0, вот сюда вставить переменную)

Comment: Макс, `translate` какой? Есть же разные `translateZ`, `translateY`, `translateX` - и зачем  тебе?

Comment: @Air  та один всего `transform:translate(0,200px);` а блин писать надо translateY... понял

Comment: @Air, я реализовал, через JS + CSS через window on scroll. хотел бы еще вытащить текст из блюра, голову ломаю, а текст с кнопкой блюрится, если есть время посмотреть, то на sferashuma.tk

Comment: @МаксимЛенский, Макс, текст блюрится, потому, что ты его родителя блюришь... Не вытащи из блока `class="banner-parallax blur"` `<h3>Music and Sound Design</h3>` сделай их соседями

Comment: @Air   у меня ни чего не блюрится ... ты перепутал меня

Comment: @МаксимЛенский, пошли в чат